# Where is the best place on Stack Exchange to post open-ended mobile code reading question

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question regarding how people effectively review code while using mass transit. I spend a lot of time on the subway, so I'd like to look over the code a little bit during the ride. I'm finding getting the code onto my iOS devices to be tedious. I wanted to ask people how they deal with this issue but I feel it's too open-ended to be appropriate to ask on Stack Overflow.

Is there a place on Stack Exchange where it would be suitable to ask this question? If so, where? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The closest site is [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), which is for "conceptual questions about software development".

**But** try to formulate your question to be specifically answerable as possible. [If you phrase it so that "every answer is equally valid", e.g. as a poll for just a list of techniques, it's likely to be closed"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) Think about how you might ask about "getting the code onto my iOS devices"—that could lead to a specific question.